The energy (or power) needed to keep a system at lower entropy
About 40% of human metabolism is used to maintain the membrane potential. Without ion pumping the K and Ca ions will equilibrate to the maximum entropy configuration. This observation is true also for the low entropy arrangement in living systems. Energy is needed to maintain this low entropy. My question is, what is the energy per unit time needed to keep a system at a lower entropy that the entropy it would naturally reach? A bit like what is the energy to rearrange stuff?
I know that in thermodynamics the formula for the change in entropy is
\delta S = \frac{delta Q}{T}
but I am not sure this formula can be used for the situation described by me.
Any ideas? References?

After you learn enough statistical thermodynamics, you will expand the understanding of entropy from that particular formula until you can cover this problem. However, this is much more like an academic paper level of study. I don't think we would be giving you a simplistic formula for this, other than the obvious way: We need to eat food to get the energy and replacement substance to expel the entropic damage, so just estimate with the energy content we absorb in food. This is well known in medicine.

Well, the basal metabolism is known, has anyone calculated the entropy of a cow compared with the entropy of all the molecules in a cow mixed at max entropy?

I think deltaQ can be calculated better by measuring the exhaled CO2 of the cow. We also know T. Thus, I think, we can calculate deltaS. The entropy of the cow is roughly constant, so this is the amount of negative entropy the cow needs by eating.

This pdf seems quite relevant, "This means that 12686 J of work must be performed to transport a mole of sodium ion from inside to the outside of the cell. ": https://faculty.washington.edu/gdrobny/Lecture452_21_14-Ion-transport.pdf

I don't even know what you mean by "the entropy that a system will reach naturally". Entropy is a function of temperature etc.. The human body, as a system, is not sufficiently characterized by temperature. You can have a wat of chemicals with the same composition as the human body that will have a well defined entropy as a function of T, but that won't be anything like a human body.

I’m voting to close this question because the term "human body" does not have a meaningful definition in physics. Physics simply does not have the tools to characterize a system as a human body.

The term "human body" appears exclusively in your comments. One can look at part of an out of equilibrium system kept at low entropy and what i the energy cost to do that keeping out of equilibrium. Just because you are not interested in a question does not mean you have to first misrepresent it and then attack this misrepresentation.

Unfortunately, a thermodynamics description of living beings is not achievable by (only) taking in account for equilibrium thermodynamics mainly for two reasons (among many other slightly less relevant ones):

Living beings, as you say, are kept in a local state of relatively low entropy with respect to the surrounding, leading to the formation of self-organized structures like cells, protein aggregates, inclusions and so on.
Due to motivation 1, living systems are highly anisotropic and they need to be kept this way in order to function, meaning that they are systems in strong non-equilibrium conditions.

Given these premises, the closest we've come to describe the thermodynamics of metabolism is due to the theory of Non-Equilibrium Thermodynamics, which essentially states that entropy is not (only) composed of its equilibrium "heat transfer" definition $\text{d}S\geq \frac{\delta{Q}}{T}$ but it can rather be described by two contributions, the entropy due to exchange of matter and energy with the outside of the system, namely $\text{d}_eS$, and the entropy production associated with any irreversible internal process for the system $\text{d}_iS$.
Prigogine, De Donder and collaborators proved that the second law of thermodynamics can be restated to say that for any process $\text{d}_iS\geq0$.
But again, we said that equilibrium should not be assumed globally, and for this motivation Non-Equilibrium thermodynamics is formulated in terms of:

position dependent intensive variables (so temperature, pressure, surface tension and any other homogeneous euler thermodynamic function of degree 0 in classical thermodynamics becomes position dependent)
position dependent density of extensive variables (so entropy density, energy density, matter density).

These conditions stem from the fundamental assumption that it is still possible to define a local equilibrium for smaller and smaller subsystems of our macroscopic system. Obviously this works up to a certain point, but the failing of local equilibrium is relevant only in extreme situations such as explosions, shock wave phenomena, and so on.
Furthermore, it can be proven that the irreversible entropy production, that is the rate of change of the irreversible entropy contribution can always be stated in terms of products of thermodynamics forces ($X_k$) and thermodynamics flows induced by forces ($J_k$).
$$\text{d}_iS=\sum_k J_k \text{d}X_k$$
Where each index is the k-th thermodynamics process taking place (chemical reaction, diffusion, creation of new interphases etc...),
Prigogine used the definition i just gave and some basic laws of continuum mechanics to prove a balance equation for the entropy density in general non-equilibrium systems. So a possible way to compute the entropy production for a system (and thus the energy dissipation), given the new restatement of the second law, would be to employ the balance equation, coupled with the right expression of each force and flow and a suitable extremum principle (there are several ones for different non-equilibrium regimes, I suggest you to check out the references given at the end).
Now, this is just a generic intro to thermodynamics applied to biophysical problems, however there are nice books on the trasduction of free energy in living beeings, so you could and should check them out also.
References:

Kondepudi, D., & Prigogine, I. (2014). Modern Thermodynamics From Heat Engines to Dissipative Structures. 2nd Edition. John Wiley & Sons.
Kondepudi, D., Petrosky, T., & Pojman, J. A. (2017). Dissipative structures and irreversibility in nature: Celebrating 100th birth anniversary of Ilya Prigogine (1917–2003). 27(10). https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5008858
Hill, T. L. (1989). Free energy transduction and biochemical cycle kinetics. Springer.

